# LLVM: how to substitute memory call to a function call passing the argument through stack?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

This is my initial code, that does not work the way I desire, but I'm kind of faced with roadblock and do not know how to proceed further.
So, basically I want to catch a tail call with a memory operand, then create a new function "__newfunc", put the memory operand (it will be used in __newfunc) to the stack and substitute initial call to "__newfunc" call.

```
  for (auto &BB: F)
    for (auto &I: BB) {
      if(CallInst *CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&I))
         // this check is not enough
         if(CI->isTailCall()) {

           LLVMContext &C = TheModule->getContext();

           AttributeList A;
           A = A.addAttribute(C, AttributeList::FunctionIndex,
                              Attribute::OptimizeNone);
           A = A.addAttribute(C, AttributeList::FunctionIndex,
                              Attribute::NoInline);
           A = A.addAttribute(C, AttributeList::FunctionIndex,
                              Attribute::NoUnwind);

           SmallVector<Type *, 3> ParamTys;
           for (unsigned i = 0; i < CI->getNumArgOperands(); i++)
             ParamTys.push_back(CI->getArgOperand(i)->getType());
           FunctionType* newFuncType =
             FunctionType::get(CI->getType(), ParamTys, false);

           Function *newFunc =
             dyn_cast<Function>(TheModule->getOrInsertFunction(
                                "__newfunc", newFuncType, A));

           BasicBlock *NewRetBlock = BasicBlock::Create(F.getContext(), "DDD", newFunc);
           ReturnInst::Create(newFunc->getContext(), nullptr, NewRetBlock);

           CI->setCalledFunction(newFunc);
       }
    }
  }
```

In the code above I find a tail call (I do not check for the memory operand yet, but it is not important now), then create a new function with arguments that the initial call has and substitute the call. (creating a "return" in the new function is for avoiding DCE removing the new function.)
Below is what I have after creating a new function, but before substitution.

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define void @foo(i64 %offset) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %0 = load void (i64)*, void (i64)** @dispatch, align 8, !tbaa !2
  tail call void %0(i64 %offset) #2
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone
define void @__newfunc(i64) #1 {
DDD:
  ret void
}
```

After substitution I have the following IR. It looks like I lost the `load`. And as a result it generates only the call to the new function, but losing the argument.

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define void @foo(i64 %offset) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %0 = load void (i64)*, void (i64)** @dispatch, align 8, !tbaa !2
  tail call void @__newfunc(i64 %offset) #2
  ret void
}
...
```

So I'm trying to find a way to make it work. I assume that I need special calling convention to be set on __newfunc, as it should accept arguments through stack only, but I do not know how to do that. Also, how to push @dispatch to a stack before calling new instruction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be getting late here, but where is the code that handles that 'memory load' argument?